# Using the maps and ggplot2 package, can you associate latlong pairs to a state

Tags: r, maps, ggplot2

As an example, suppose that I have the latlong pairs of every McDonald's restaurant in the US, and nothing else.  Can I use the maps/ggplot2 packages to, i.e. put a circle at the center of each state whose radius is proportional to the number of McDonald's?

Thanks!

Comment: the `splancs` package has an `inout` function that might help, but there is probably a simpler way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should have looked at the maps reference guide.  The function map.where does the trick nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the Spatial Task View, linked in the docs from the main CRAN site. This functionality is in the sp package and the rgeos package.

Answer (score 0):

Another faster way is to use the function `over` of `sp` package. In fact, the database of `map.where` is fairly outdated (look at the Europe!). 
You need a `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` with the US Borders and a data frame with the latlong pairs, then you need to convert the data frame to `SpatialPoints` and you can use finally the `over` function. The following code can be used for example on the world map provided by `maptools` package.

```
require(sp)
require(maptools)
data(wrld_simpl)
pts = SpatialPoints(my_lat_long_pairs_data_frame, CRS(proj4string(wrld_simpl)))
my_countries = over(pts, wrld_simpl)$NAME
```